# How to make dropdown menu content centered horizontally and full width

Tags: html, css

When you hover over any of the middle navigation items, there is a horizontal dropdown.  I want the dropdown background to stretch to be full width and have the dropdown menu elements centered around where you hovered.

I tried changing the display to flex for the .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content, but the dropdown elements stretch across the screen and it makes it hard to mouseover it.

```js
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
      if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
      } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
      }
    }
```

```css
  .site-logo {
        margin-top: 2em;
    }
    
    .site-footer .email-newsletter .email-submit-btn {
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .site-header .primary-navigation .navigation-item-group {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #444444;
    }
    .utility-navigation .nav-item.cart-nav-item {
        background-color: #333333;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    .topnav {
      overflow: hidden;
      margin-top: 3em;
      padding-top: 0.5em;
          display: inline;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 3.5%;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        float: right;
        text-align: right;
        clear: right;
        margin-top: 3em;
        padding-top: 1em;
        padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    }
    .topnav a {
      float: left;
      padding-bottom: 2em;
    }
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
     transition: all 0.3s linear;
    }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 769px) {
      .topnav {
     position: relative;
     padding-bottom: 1em;
        padding-top: 1em;
     }
      .topnav .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
      }
      .topnav a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .topnav .dropdown {float: none;}
      .topnav .dropdown-content {
       position: relative;
       float:none;
       text-align:center;
       }
      .topnav .dropdown .dropbtn {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .dropdown-content a {
        float: none !important;
        text-align: center !important;
    }
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
    }
    
    .topnav a {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: 600;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #444444;
    }
    
    .topnav .icon {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .dropdown .dropbtn {
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      padding: 14px 20px;
      background-color: white;
      font-family: inherit;
      margin: 0;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: 600;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #444444;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: flex;
      visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: white;
        position: absolute;
        top: auto;
        right: 0;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      float: right;
      padding: 20px 23px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    
    body.home .site-header .container {
        padding-bottom: 1em;
    }
    img.nav-img {
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="#" class="active">  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/220px-SNice.svg.png" height="22" class="nav-img">Calendar</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn"> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/220px-SNice.svg.png" height="22" class="nav-img">About 
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Music</a>
          <a href="#">More</a>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn"> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/220px-SNice.svg.png" height="22" class="nav-img">Tickets 
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Subscriptions</a>
          <a href="#">Music</a>
          <a href="#">Tickets</a>
          <a href="#">More</a>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn"> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/220px-SNice.svg.png" height="22" class="nav-img">Community
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Learning Programs</a>
          <a href="#">More</a>
        </div>
      </div> 
        <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn"> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/220px-SNice.svg.png" height="22" class="nav-img">Visit
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Seating Charts</a>
          <a href="#">More</a>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/220px-SNice.svg.png" height="22" class="nav-img">Give
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Donate Now!</a>
          <a href="#">More</a>
        </div>
      </div> 
        <a href="#" class="active"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/220px-SNice.svg.png" height="22" class="nav-img">Shop</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
```

I expect the dropdown menu to generate when a user hovers over the navigation and the background to be full width.  Also, the dropdown menu elements should be centered around where you hover.  It should be similar to the laphil.org navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

You're going to want to change `.dropdown-content` to:

```
.dropdown-content {
  display: flex;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  width: 100vw;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

In `.dropdown-content`, notice the addition of the `width` and `text-align` properties, as well as removing the `right` property.

You'll also want to create a new div that your dropdown links are wrapped in, like so:

```
<div class="dropdown-content">
     <div class="sample">
          <a href="#">Subscriptions</a>
          <a href="#">Music</a>
          <a href="#">Tickets</a>
          <a href="#">More</a>
      </div>
</div>
```

And in this case, the new `sample` div has the styling:

```
.sample {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

Here's a working codepen: https://codepen.io/raymondwclark/pen/Bgvdwy

Comment: Oh this is almost there!  Now it's full width, but it's not centered around where you hover.  I see that I wrote that above, but not in the bottom of the my question.  I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you say "centered around where you hover".  But I took a look at laphil.org and modeled the nav after that.  If you mean you want the nav links to be positioned according to the mouse you may have to take into account mouseposition

Comment: You're right.  I added some spacing between the dropdown elements and it looks much more like the laphil.  Thanks for your help!